# Redirecting multiple IIS sites sharing the same codebase in IIS7

Tags: redirect, iis-7, web-config

I have two IIS sites setup which point to the same code. I need one of the sites to redirect and the other one not to. In IIS6 I could simply add the redirect to the correct site and only that site would redirect. In IIS7 if I add the redirect to either site it is automatically added to the web.config and both sites end up redirecting because they share the same web.config. Is there any way to prevent this behavior? Maybe some sort of conditional statement in the web.config that checks the host header before redirecting? I've seen other similar problems explained on here but nothing where two sites use the same web.config...